# What does "capacity achieving code" mean?

Tags: communication, digital-communications, capacity, encoding

I am an electrical engineer passed several courses in information theory and coding theory, however as I think now, I see that I have not understand the basic ideas in these concepts till now.

We know that each channel has a capacity that is achieved by a specific input distribution. For example an AWGN channel has a capacity of $$\frac{1}{2}\log{(1+SNR)}$$ and is achieved for input distribution of Gaussian. Now I want to transmit 0 and 1 with equal probabilities through this channel. Obviously I cannot reach capacity, as the distribution of input is not Gaussian.

In the books we see that ... code is capacity achieving, I cannot understanding what does this term "capacity achieving code" mean. Can anyone explain more?

Comment: Your formula is incomplete because it does not include the bandwidth of the channel.  Also, I believe that the Gaussian requirement refers to the distribution of the noise in the channel and not to the method of transmitting information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The channel capacity is the largest rate at which communication can be made with arbitrary small error. This means that if you decide for a rate that is above the channel capacity, you will have to live with some errors in your received code word.

Your formula
\begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{2}\log(1+SNR)
\end{equation}
tells you how many bits/s/Hz per **real dimension** you can transmit in order to have a chance at zero errors at the receiver. Note that this is normalized with respect to bandwidth, you could also write
\begin{equation}
\frac{W}{2}\log(1+SNR), \quad SNR = \frac{P}{N_0W}.
\end{equation}
to get the capacity in bits/s per real dimension. This formula is derived from the fact that for the AWGN channel, the input that maximizes the mutual information is Gaussian distributed.

Now, the channel capacity tells you that it is **possible** to transmit at this rate but it does not tell you **how** to do it. This is where channel coding enters. So channel coding aims to add redundancy to what you transmit in a structured way to protect the information. If the errors induced when using the code is approaching zero when the blocklength grows larger, this code is said to achieve capacity.

An example from "Fundamentals of Wireless Communication" by David Tse and Pramod Viswanat: The capacity of the AWGN channel at 0 dB SNR is 0.5 bits. There are LDPC codes that are a couple of thousand bits long that result in error rates on the order of 10^-4. By incresaing the blocklength, the error rate would also decrease. Hence, by making the block to transmit extremely long, you would approach zero error. So the LDPC code is capacity achieving.

Comment: The LDPC example is incomplete. The important part, that is not mentioned above, for deciding if an error correction code achieves capacity is the rate of the LDPC code.